# Aspectj get business layer logger calls and put them into a REST response object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, aspectj

We are developing a web application using Spring with a layered architecture (REST service layer, business layer and repository).
For each REST service we are returning a generic RestResponse object, which has a data field and a list for messages and errors.

Though when we need to perform validation on the data we get in the REST layer, we can do it either in that layer or the business layer (or both). I thought of an idea to only do validation in the business layer to avoid duplicating code.

My thinking was that when we create a RestResponse object in the REST layer, we then set data to it by calling the business layer method. In that business method we would do validation and call Logger to log some messages (warnings or errors). Using aspectj these logger calls would be intercepted and their arguments (the message) would be put directly in our RestResponse message list.

To make it clearer here are some code samples:

**The object returned to the client from the REST layer**

```
public class RestResponse<T> {
    private T data;
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList();

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public final List<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<String> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
}
```

**The Rest controller**

```
@RestController
public class TestRestController {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceImpl service;

    @RequestMapping("")
    public RestResponse<?> callService() {

        RestResponse<String> response = new RestResponse<>();
        // We would only set data, message list would be populated in the aspect from logger call arguments
        response.setData(service.returnData());
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class.getName());

    public String returnData() {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "Some warning message");
        return "Some data...";
    }
}
```

**Aspect class that gets the message list from RestResponse and adds messages to it**

```
@Aspect
public class RestAspect {

    @Pointcut("call(* java.util.logging.Logger.log(..)) " +
            "&& cflow(execution(* com.gg.spring.tests.services.ServiceImpl.returnData(..))) " +
            "&& cflow(execution(* com.gg.spring.tests.rest.TestRestController.callService(..)))" +
            "&& !within(RestAspect)")
    private void logPointcut() {
    }

    @Pointcut("call(com.gg.spring.tests.rest.RestResponse.new()) " +
            "&& cflow(execution(* com.gg.spring.tests.rest.TestRestController.callService(..)))" +
            "&& !within(RestAspect)")
    private void afterConstructingResponsePointcut() {
    }

    private List<String> messages;

    @Around(value = "logPointcut()")
    public void loggerCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Object[] response = joinPoint.getArgs();
        synchronized (this.messages) {
            this.messages.add((String) response[1]);
        }
    }

    @AfterReturning(returning = "response", pointcut = "afterConstructingResponsePointcut()")
    public void firstCall(JoinPoint jp, RestResponse response) {
        synchronized (response.getMessages()) {
            this.messages = response.getMessages();
        }
    }
}
```

I seem to have got it working with this code, however, when I test with many threads I get some RestResponse objects with 0 messages, or some with 3 messages, but each one of them should have only 1 message since that's how many times I call log method in my service method.

With the test I wrote I create 128 threads, each of them calling the Rest layer method 1000 times and out of 128 000 calls 200 have a different number of messages than is supposed to be. Doesn't seem to be a high number but can be very significant in the right scenario.

Has anyone done something like this in the past and could share their experience? There are other ways to do this, but if this was working it would be a nice way to have less code. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to fix this. The simplest one is to just use a thread-local variable in your aspect. Then you do not need synchronized blocks anymore either. The latter do not solve your problem anyway because the problem is that multiple threads write into the same aspect member, the aspect being a singleton.

```java
@Aspect
public class RestAspect {

  @Pointcut(
    "call(* java.util.logging.Logger.log(..)) "
    + "&& args(*, logMessage)"
    + "&& cflow(execution(* com.gg.spring.tests.services.ServiceImpl.returnData(..))) "
    + "&& cflow(execution(* com.gg.spring.tests.rest.TestRestController.callService(..)))"
    + "&& !within(RestAspect)")
  private void logPointcut(String logMessage) { }

  @Pointcut(
    "call(com.gg.spring.tests.rest.RestResponse.new()) "
    + "&& cflow(execution(* com.gg.spring.tests.rest.TestRestController.callService(..)))"
    + "&& !within(RestAspect)")
  private void afterConstructingResponsePointcut() {}

  private ThreadLocal<List<String>> messages = new ThreadLocal<>();

  @Around("logPointcut(logMessage)")
  public void loggerCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String logMessage) {
    this.messages.get().add(logMessage);
  }

  @AfterReturning(returning = "response", pointcut = "afterConstructingResponsePointcut()")
  public void firstCall(JoinPoint jp, RestResponse<String> response) {
    this.messages.set(response.getMessages());
  }
}
```

I wrote a test program like yours (128 threads, 1000 calls per thread) and could reproduce your problem as well as confirm that my solution works.

BTW, I also changed the aspect a little bit so as to use `args()` parameter binding rather than `jp.getArgs()`.

---

Another way to solve this would be to use non-singleton instantiation for your aspect, such as `percflow`. But then you need to use native AspectJ syntax.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but thanks for your help!
Having a threadLocal variable solved my problem